# Get product of different categories in mysql having separate limit for each id

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'Product' like this

```
 id | Category_id | ProductName | Quantity
 ...........................................
 1  |    2        |    ABC      |  4     
 2  |    2        |    DEF      |  2
 3  |    2        |    GHI      |  4
 4  |    2        |    JKL      |  1
 5  |    2        |    MNO      |  4
 6  |    2        |    PQR      |  4
 7  |    2        |    STU      |  4
 8  |    3        |    VWX      |  4
 9  |    3        |    YZA      |  4
 10 |    3        |    YAB      |  4
 11 |    3        |    YCD      |  4
 12 |    4        |    YEF      |  4
 13 |    5        |    YGH      |  4
```

I want to fetch product of Category_id 2 and 3 with limit 5.
Note : Product from each category must be display after applying limit.
Expected output: Fetched total five rows containing random data from each Category_id 2 and 3

**Output :**

```
 id | Category_id | ProductName | Quantity
 ...........................................
 5  |    2        |    MNO      |  4
 6  |    2        |    PQR      |  4
 7  |    2        |    STU      |  4
 8  |    3        |    VWX      |  4
 9  |    3        |    YZA      |  4
```

Data order may be changed

Comment: provide expected output

Comment: Please also provide an example of what you have already tried

Comment: I am not going to use UNION,
Expected output: Fetched total five rows containing data from each Category_id 2 and 3

Comment: "Having separate limit for each id" - I do not understand *this* statement in the context of *that* result set, and what are you ordering on

Comment: @Strawberry i just want to fetch total 5 rows from above table but 5 rows is a combination of data of Category_id = 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
SELECT id, Quantity, ProductName, Category_id
FROM (
    SELECT id, Quantity, ProductName, Category_id,
           @row_number:= CASE 
                            WHEN @cid = Category_id THEN @row_number+1
                            ELSE 1
                         END AS row_number,
           @cid:=Category_id
    FROM (       
       SELECT id, Quantity, ProductName, Category_id
       FROM products
       WHERE Category_id IN (2, 3)
       ORDER BY Category_id, RAND() ) s ) t
ORDER BY row_number, Category_id
LIMIT 5
```

The above query will select a total of 5 records from categories 2, 3, *trying to balance the number of records fetched from each category*: 3 records will be fetched from category 2, whereas 2 records will be fecthed from category 3.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06833/1)

Comment: While brilliant, I see nothing to indicate that this is actually what the OP wants.

Comment: @Strawberry I agree, it's just a wild guess based on the sample data he provides as expected result!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is you may get the two queries separately and use UNION ALL

```
(
  select *
  from Product
  where `Category_id ` = 2
  order by ProductName desc
  LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL
(
  select *
  from Product
  where `Category_id ` = 3
  order by ProductName desc
  LIMIT 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So why not

```
 7  |    2        |    STU      |  4
 8  |    3        |    VWX      |  4
 9  |    3        |    YZA      |  4
 10 |    3        |    YAB      |  4
 11 |    3        |    YCD      |  4
```

?

This result set corresponds perfectly with your stated criteria.